# Finding the key of the max value in a javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, key, max

I have an empty array into which I am pushing values using javascript. I am able to find the max value of the array and set that to a variable using the following:

```
Array.max = function( array ){
    return Math.max.apply( Math, array );
};

var maxX = Array.max(xArray);
```

How can I find the key associated with that value?

Comment: You mean, the index? And what should be the logic if multiple indexes have the maximum value? (e.g. [1, 4, 2, 4])

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the values are unique, you could use [`Array.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
var maxX = Array.max(xArray);
var index = xArray.indexOf(maxX);
```

If the keys are not unique, `index` will contain the key of the first element found. If the value does not exist at all, the "key" will be `-1`.

Comment: Array.max() is not even an existing function, I believe you meant Math.max.apply()

Comment: for me I had to spread my array inside Math.max like  `Math.max(...[1, 2, 3])`